# How to express $A^{-1}$ in the form of $\alpha I+\beta A$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix whose eigen-values are $1,1$ and $3$. Express $A^{-1}$ in the form $\alpha I +\beta A$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p(x)=(x-1)(x-3)=x^2-4x+3$. By Cayley-Hamilton:

$$A^2-4A+3I=0.$$

This gives

$$A-4I+3A^{-1}=0.$$

Comment: The Cayley-Hamilton theorem doesn’t address the *minimal* polynomial per se.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha,\beta\in \Bbb R$ such that $A^{-1}=\alpha I+\beta A$. Then $$A(\alpha I+\beta A)=\alpha A+ \beta A^2=I$$

This is equivalent to say that $\beta A^2 + \alpha A-I=0$, that is $A$ is a solution of the polynomial $$p(x)=\beta x^2+\alpha x-1=0.$$ This is also equivalent to say that the eigenvalues $1,3$ are solutions of $p(x)$.
Let $q(x)=(x-1)(x-3)=x^2-4x+3$, then $$p(x)=-\frac13q(x)=-\frac13 x^2+\frac43 x -1.$$ Hence $\alpha=\frac43$ and $\beta=-\frac13$.

Comment: An argument is needed why the minimal polynomial cannot be $(x-1)^2(x-3)$. If $A$ could be any $3\times 3$ matrix (that is, if we drop the condition that the matrix be symetric), then this is in fact possible, and then the problem has no solution. Because of the condition that the maxtrix be symmetric and real, however, we know that it is diagonalizable. In particular all Jordan blocks have size $1$, and then the minimal polynomial is a product of different unary polynomials.